# linux command to find files and replace with another file

Tags: linux, shell, sed, command

I'm looking for a linux command to search a folder directory and it's subfolders for a file by name and replace all of them with a copy of another file. Any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you have the replacement file in your home directory (~), you can use find to do the replacing.  This will find all boom.txt files and replace them with the replace.txt file (keeping the boom.txt name).

```
find . -name "boom.txt" -exec cp ~/replace.txt {} \;
```

Comment: Is there a way to not keep the boom.txt name and use the new file name instead?

Answer (score -1):

Adding to the answer by user1683793, the following command can also be an alternative for the copy and replace. This command is verified on **Mintty**(Windows 10).

```
find . -name "boom.txt" -print -exec cp ~/replace.txt {} \;
```